# Macbook M1 assembly lldb displays only 3 source lines then switches to object code display

Tags: lldb, arm64

First attempt at ARM64 (apple M1) assembly coding. Have basic 'hello world' code which assembles and runs correctly but when I run it in lldb, only the first three lines are displayed in full source code format like this:

```
Abenaki:hello jiml$ ~/llvm/clang+llvm-15.0.2-arm64-apple-darwin21.0/bin/lldb hello
(lldb) target create "hello"
Current executable set to '/Users/jiml/Projects/GitRepos/ARM/hello/hello/hello/hello' (arm64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = hello`main + 4, address = 0x0000000100003f7c
(lldb) r
Process 5017 launched: '/Users/jiml/Projects/GitRepos/ARM/hello/hello/hello/hello' (arm64)
Process 5017 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f7c hello`main at hello.s:19
   16   
   17   _main:
   18       mov     x0, #0x0            // stdout
-> 19       adrp    x1, msg@PAGE        // pointer to string
   20       add     x1, x1, msg@PAGEOFF
   21       ldr     x2, =msg_len        // bytes to output
   22       mov     x16, #0x04          // sys_write
warning: This version of LLDB has no plugin for the language "assembler". Inspection of frame variables will be limited.
(lldb)
```

After three steps, the display reverts to bare object code like this:

```
(lldb) s
Process 5017 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f88 hello`main + 16
hello`main:
->  0x100003f88 <+16>: mov    x16, #0x4
    0x100003f8c <+20>: svc    #0x80
    0x100003f90 <+24>: adrp   x1, 1
    0x100003f94 <+28>: mov    x2, #0x0
```

dwarfdump -a shows that all source lines are present in the .o; same behavior for .dSYM assembly. Using the 'list' command in lldb however displays all source lines correctly.

Is this a known issue for LLVM (clang, lldb) development? Any help appreciated...

I have tried LLVM version 14 and 15, same behavior, searched for similar issues but no help.

I did find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778648/why-is-it-that-assembling-linking-in-one-step-loses-debug-info-for-my-assembly-s but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: The source lines might all be present, but their range might not cover all of main, either because some code was just compiler generated but not associated with a specific source line, or because of compiler bugs - particularly if you aren't building at -O0.  You can see the source map with all the ranges by using `source info -f hello.s`.  You can ask lldb what it knows about a particular address with `image lookup -va <address>`.  That might give some insight into why this code doesn't have an associated  source line number.

Comment: If that still seems wrong, it's best to file a report with the llvm bug reporter: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/.  Be sure to include your input .s file and your compile line and the versions of clang & lldb you are using.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have this resolved but not sure if it is actual compiler bug.

I wrote hello world in C, compiled and confirmed complete source display in lldb. I then reran clang with -S to generate the assembler source.

I then assembled that source...

```
clang -g -c -o hello.o hello.s
clang -o hello hello.o -lSystem -arch arm64
```

and confirmed it also runs in lldb with complete source display. Then I moved my hand written code line-by-line in order to figure out where the problem occurs. Seems my string data and length calculation is problematic. In the data section I originally had:

```
msg: ascii "Hello ARM64\n"
msg_len = . - msg
```

Coming from Intel world this seems perfectly natural ;-) Adding that length calculation caused some sort of corruption of the debug data. However, the executable has a proper OSO statement pointing at hello.o (nm -ap hello) and further the object file has references for all source statements in the source file (dwarfdump --debug-line hello.o) but still doesn't display source code after the third step. Curious that 'source info -f hello.s' within lldb only listed four lines.

I found three work-arounds. First adding a label between the two statements seems to allow correct behavior:

```
msg: ascii "Hello ARM64\n"
nothing:
msg_len = . - msg
```

Second, using equate:

```
msg: ascii "Hello ARM64\n"
.equ msg_len, . - msg
```

Third, using two labels:

```
msg: ascii "Hello ARM64\n"
msg_end:
msg_len = msg_end - msg
```

Will file report with llvm and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of further suggestions that I have found useful while debugging similar problem:

- `dwarfdump -v --debug-info <file>` provides information on how the line table is formed by line table commands (Great description of line programs: https://swatinem.de/blog/dwarf-lines/);
- I have noticed that lldb handles incorrectly source lines if one address is missing between two addresses that have a line entry;
- Addresses that have end_sequence tag seem to be ignored even if they also have entries before which don't have the tag (spec asks for the end_sequence address to point after useful entries, so it is correct, but a bit surprising);
- Finally, lldb support varies for DWARF4/DWARF5 and it may be interesting to do `-gdwarf-4`.